# Python Tweepy - Searching for string in list - possible encoding issue

Tags: python, twitter, ascii, tweepy

I am attempting to filter out duplicate (retweeted) tweets which are returned from a list of results. I thought I could simply create a list and check to see whether the text of a tweet is already in the list, if not then I add it to the list. The section of the code where I'm attempting this is as follows-

```
searched_tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=search, since=since_time, include_entities=True).items(max_tweets)

filtered_tweets =[]

for filtered in searched_tweets:

    if str(filtered_tweets).find(str(filtered.text.encode('ascii', 'ignore')))== -1:
        filtered_tweets.append(filtered)
```

This does not work as it essentially always returns true even where the posts already exists. I suspect this is due to the text encoding? As the endcoded string I'm searching for has essentially had parts removed? Any advice on how to overcome this would be welcome.

Comment: yeah perhaps encoding is the problem. why not encoding both reference and substring in `unicode` at first (before `find`)?

Comment: Thanks ahmad, I'm not sure I can (or know how) as I cant encode the list, do you mean to loop through the list each time and encode the items as ascii?

Comment: Put these three lines at the very first lines, near imports, to change the encoding globally to UTF-8: 1) `import sys`, 2) `reload(sys)`, 3) `sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')`.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way to filter out retweets would be:

```
for tweet in searched_tweets:    
    if hasattr(tweet,"retweeted_status"):
        continue

    #if you have reached this line, your tweet is not a retweet
    #do stuff with your tweet
```